# Laravel testing with PHPUnit and Mockery - Setting up dependencies on Controller test

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-4

After finally getting my stupid simple test to pass, I have a feeling that I'm not doing it correctly.

I have a SessionsController, that is responsible for displaying a login page and logging a user in.

I have decided not to use facades so that I wouldn't have to extend Laravel's TestCase and take a performance hit on my unit tests. Therefore, I have injected all the dependencies through the controller, like so -

**SessionsController** - Constructor

```
public function __construct(UserRepositoryInterface $user, 
                            AuthManager $auth, 
                            Redirector $redirect,
                            Environment $view )
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->redirect = $redirect; 
    $this->view = $view;
}
```

I have done the necessary declaring of variables and using the namespaces, which I'm not going to include here as its unnecessary.

the create method detects if a user is authorized, if they are then I redirect them to the home page, otherwise they are displayed the login form.

**SessionsController** - Create

```
public function create()
{
    if ($this->auth->user()) return $this->redirect->to('/');

    return $this->view->make('sessions.login');
}
```

Now for the testing, I'm brand new to it, so bear with me.

**SessionsControllerTest**

```
class SessionsControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {


    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function test_logged_in_user_cannot_see_login_page()
    {
        # Arrange (Create mocked versions of dependencies)

        $user = Mockery::mock('Glenn\Repositories\User\UserRepositoryInterface');

        $authorizedUser = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager');
        $authorizedUser->shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn(true);

        $redirect = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Routing\Redirector');
        $redirect->shouldReceive('to')->once()->andReturn('redirected to home');

        $view = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\View\Environment');


        # Act (Attempt to go to login page)

        $session = new SessionsController($user, $authorizedUser, $redirect, $view);
        $result = $session->create();

        # Assert (Return to home page) 
    }
}
```

This all passes, but I don't want to have to declare all of these mocked dependencies for each test that I write in my SessionsControllerTest. Is there a way to declare these mocked dependencies once in say a constructor? and then call them by there variables for mocking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `setUp` method to declare any dependencies that are global for the entire test class.  It's similar to the `tearDown` method you're currently using:

```
public function setUp()
{
   // This method will automatically be called prior to any of your test cases
   parent::setUp();

   $this->userMock = Mockery::mock('Glenn\Repositories\User\UserRepositoryInterface');
}
```

However that won't work if your set up for the mock differs between tests.  For this case you can use a helper method:

```
protected function getAuthMock($isLoggedIn = false)
{
    $authorizedUser = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager');
    $authorizedUser->shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn($isLoggedIn);
}
```

Then when you need the auth mock you can just call `getAuthMock`.  This can greatly simplify your tests.

**However**

I don't think you're testing your controller correctly.  You shouldn't instantiate the controller object yourself, instead you should utilize the `call` method which exists in Laravel's `TestCase` class.  Try checking out [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-laravel-controllers--net-31456) about testing Laravel Controllers by Jeffrey Way.  I think you're looking to do something more along the lines of this in your test:

```
class SessionsControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function test_logged_in_user_cannot_see_login_page()
    {
        // This will bind any instances of the Auth manager during 
        // the next request to the mock object returned from the 
        // function below
        App::instance('Illuminate\Auth\Manager', $this->getAuthMock(true));

        // Act
        $this->call('/your/route/to/controller/method', 'GET');

        // Assert
        $this->assertRedirectedTo('/');

    }

    protected function getAuthMock($isLoggedIn)
    {
        $authMock = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Auth\Manager');
        $authMock->shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn($isLoggedIn);
        return $authMock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @watcher! I appreciate your thorough answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a "helper".  Move the creation of the mocked dependencies into another function, then call that when you need them. Check out slide 52 in this presentation: https://speakerdeck.com/jcarouth/guiding-object-oriented-design-with-tests-1 (well check out the whole thing, but the example is on slide 52)

Edit: The setUp way is even better, I was thinking for something you didn't need in ALL the tests, but I think for what you described doing it in the setUp is way better.

Comment: Thank you for this reference @Jessica, I appreciate it.