# Laravel: Dependency Inject Auth

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, dependency-injection

How do I dependency inject Auth in Laravel?

Like this:

```
 public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
      $this->auth = $auth;

    }
```

If I do that then this does not work:

```
$user_type = Auth::user()->user_type;
```

Answer (score 12):

You should type hint `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager`:

```
public function __construct(Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager $auth)
{
  $this->auth = $auth;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. When I run a test... $user_type = $this->auth->user()->user_type; ... fails

Comment: Do you have a user session present? Because trying to get `$this->auth->user()->user_type` with no user session, will most definitely throw a `Trying to get property of non-object` exception.

Comment: Hi, apologies! I am trying to unit test a controller and the above code is causing an error. Originally I just used the facade pattern for Auth but that caused the same issue.

Comment: In that case you should mock the `AuthManager` for your test. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23374376/351330).

Comment: Aha that's what i've been looking  for.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to inject Auth, you actually need to inject this class:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
```

That will resolve everything what you define inside:

```
config/auth.php
```

If you want to extend Auth you can do that but only for:

1. Guard Driver which is Guard Class - it needs to implement Guard or StatefulGuard interface.
2. Provider which is UserProvider Class - it needs to implement UserProvider interface.

Standard Auth Guard drivers in Laravel / Lumen are:

1. SessionGuard
2. TokenGuard

Standard Auth UserProviders are in Laravel / Lumen are:

1. EloquentUserProvider
2. DatabaseUserProvider

More about extending Auth you have in official Laravel documentation. See link below:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/extending#authentication

This is the code which I have in my controller and it is working like a charm:

```
    public function createToken(Request $request, Guard $guard)
    {
//        return 'in progress...';
    }
```

Best Practise for extending Auth class is in ServiceProvider boot() method.

Hope this helps!

Cheers.